# error while trying to display view in asp.net mvc 3 app?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am trying to display a list in a View, how to fix this error?

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,mvc3Post.Models.Contact]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[mvc3Post.Models.Contact]'.

controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AdventureWorksEntities db = new AdventureWorksEntities();

        var result = from soh in db.SalesOrderHeaders
                     join co in db.Contacts
                     on soh.ContactID equals co.ContactID
                     orderby co.FirstName
                     group co by co.ContactID into g
                     select g;
        return View(result.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

view:

```
@model IEnumerable<mvc3Post.Models.Contact>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            NameStyle
        </th>
        <th>
            Title
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameStyle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ContactID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ContactID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ContactID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated now that I see the controller method:

You might need to transform your LINQ result set into a list or something (e.g., `contacts.ToList()`) more concrete.

Another alternative might be to create a root object for your page's list object to live on. I find it a little easier to follow and maintain if each View has a corresponding Model class that represents it's entire state.

I think either route will resolve your issue though. I think that the latter is probably the better way if I had to recommend one vs the other.

Comment: the controller method is given see above:)